how to configure otel.javaagent to print logs in JSON format
I'm using otel.javaagent to instrument my code and I'm using JUL(java.util.logging) for logging.
I have defined a custom JsonFormatter for my console logging and have registered in logging.properties e.g.
  java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=my.example.JsonFormatter

this formatter is being picked up by OTEL API where I create spans (since they use JUL as well).
But not by otel.javaagent .
based on otel.javaagent docs, it seems it has OTEL_JAVAAGENT_LOGGING that can be set to simple, application or none (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/zero-code/java/agent/configuration/)
Is otel.javaagent  also uses JUL or other libs?
and how can a customer log fomatter be set for it?
